# How do I generate a rough outline around a shape in geo nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

Okay, I'm making a custom patch generator so I can turn .svg s that I make into patches. I'm trying to streamline the process because I'm working on a project that calls for like a hundred of them unique. I dissected and used the embroidery text from one of blender's open movies 'Charge' as a base, I'm going to use it as a border; my next step is to make a felt background the embroidery would be attached to, how would I go about creating a rough outline around the geometry I'm using. I'm thinking using a curve would work best but I can't figure it out. [image: The blue outline is where the patch background would lead up to]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

something like this?

[image]

If you need to keep the concave angles, try this node setup (lower performances)

[image]

[image]

If the object you want an outline on is 3D rather than 2D you can use a node setup like this

[image]

Comment: Holy crap you're a life saver man, thanks infinitely.